# why is my plot not showing the line? using semilogy

Tags: matlab

Im trying to plot iterations vs error_delta but its not showing.
but its not showing the line of plotting.
We suppose to plot the iterations as the error_delta is in the y-axis, with the error_delta= abs(root_delta-x);

```
% root for f(x) = cos(x)
paso = 0.5e-10;
N = 100;
x= 1.0; %initial guess.
i = 0;
eps = 1;
root_delta = 4.6; 
figure(1);
hold on;
while eps >= paso && i <= N  %while loop to iterate
    y = x - (cos(x)/(-sin(x)));
    eps = abs(y-x);
    x= y;
    error_delta = abs(root_delta - x);
    i = i+1;
    disp('    root      iteration');
    disp([x',i',error_delta']);
    semilogy(i,error_delta);
    xlabel('iterations');
    ylabel('error Delta');
end
disp(y);
disp(i);
```

Comment: "Solution 2" of Matt's answer should suffice.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are having here is that [`semilogy` works like `plot`](https://au.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/semilogy.html?searchHighlight=semilogy&s_tid=doc_srchtitle) does and requires arrays of data (one for each axis) to plot a line between them. In your situation it would be good to create these arrays inside of your while loop by indexing them and then using the `semilogy` function afterwards, this code works for me (NOTE: Defining `it` and `error_delta` like that is considered bad practice as the array changes size on every loop. If you have a way of knowing how big they will be before the loop runs, please initialize them with the [`zeros`](http://au.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/zeros.html) function):

```
% root for f(x) = cos(x)

%% Define parameters
paso = 0.5e-10;
N = 100;
x = 1.0; 
i = 1;
eps = 1;
root_delta = 4.6; 

%% Allocate arrays
it = [];
error_data = [];

%% Generate data
while eps >= paso && i <= N  
    y = x - (cos(x)/(-sin(x)));
    eps = abs(y-x);
    x = y;
    error_delta(i) = abs(root_delta - x); %#ok<SAGROW>
    it(i) = i; %#ok<SAGROW>
    i = i + 1;
end

%% Plot data
figure(1);
semilogy(it,error_delta);
xlabel('Iterations');
ylabel('Error \delta');
```

Comment: @LuisGarcia Not a problem, happy to help!